# Optimize quality of livestream

Tags: video-streaming

I have a twitch streaming channel, and am disappointed with the quality of the streams that result. I know my computer is capable of pushing out a higher quality stream.

[My stream](http://www.twitch.tv/entertheshen/profile) so you can see. It sometimes looks crisp, but when things start happening edges get blurry.

I'm new to streaming, so I bet it is settings related. I use OBS as my streaming client.

Will post settings if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because your upload speed isn't high enough. Run a test at [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/) and let us know what the upload speed is (specify Mbps or MB/s).

Here are two resources I used for setting up my stream.

YouTube video: [Best OBS Settings for Slow Internet Twitch Streaming (720p with 1mb Upload)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=873VCQGKiho).

Upload speed charts:

- [720p](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A7CEZfJIAewWXi5QUkhaALbdukZLMHPZr_GtDa8x3BA/edit#gid=1)
- [1080p](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGIkfEBrM9oKcbtd6Lhhpk2tdiEoRjALDPMwDkXCIXk/edit#gid=2)

720p 60fps can look better than 1080p at 30fps so it's up to you which to go with. Play around with the settings and see what looks best. In OBS settings, under Encoding, make sure the Max Bitrate and Buffer Size match what your upload speed is. While stream is running, there is a Dropped Frames stat at the bottom of OBS. If you're getting a large amount of dropped frames, lower the settings.

Comment: I have gigabit up and down. Let me look into those resources and get back to you

Comment: Upload speed shouldn't be a problem then. Is that what's promised by the ISP or actually tested? The max bitrate recommended for Twitch is 3000-3500 kbps so I would set it to that in OBS.

Comment: Should base resolution be 1080p (My monitors are set to that) with a downscale to 720p?

Comment: My bitrate max was set at1000, that likely was a major bottleneck, I'm going to try streaming with that at 720p 60fps and see how it goes.

Comment: I was streaming at 1080p 60fps with a bitrate of 2000 so you should be fine to keep it at 1080p with 3500.

Comment: cool, ill try 1080p on next stream and compare the two.